# Amazon S3 with node rest API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload my data using postman. I have integrated amazon s3 bucket with it. But after I try to POST particular data, the postman throws an error: "Access Denied".
Here is my code:

```
    exports.vehicles_create_vehicle = (req, res, next) => {


    const vehicle = new Vehicle({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: req.body.name,
      category: req.body.category,
      price: req.body.price,
      vehicleImage: req.files[0].location,
      baseFare: req.body.baseFare,

    });
    vehicle
      .save()
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
          message: "Created product successfully",
          createdProduct: {
            name: result.name,
            price: result.price,
            category: result.category,
            _id: result._id,
            request: {
              type: "GET",
              url: "http://localhost:3000/vehicles/" + result._id
            }
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        });
      });
  };
```

And here is my bucket coding:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk')
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3')


aws.config.update({
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
  secretAccessKey:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  region: 'us-east-2'
})

var s3 = new aws.S3()

var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'one-way-travel',
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now()+file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, '-'));
    }
  })
})
```

I could not understand the reason for the error. Please help to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot HTTP 403: Access Denied errors from Amazon S3, check the following:

- Permissions for bucket and object owners across AWS accounts
- Issues in bucket policy or AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) user policies
- User credentials to access Amazon S3
- VPC endpoint policy
- Missing object
- Object encryption by AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS)
- Requester Pays enabled on bucket
- AWS Organizations service control policy

Source: [Amazon Knowledge Center](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/).

Comment: Could you post your bucket policy?